# Cocoon callbacks aren't fired when called from rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, apache-cocoon

I have a page with nested fields that works well in development environment.
I use an after-insert callback to number the field labels. So this creates the "pericoop 1, pericoop 2" labels.
However, when I test the page from rspec, the labels aren't numbered. When I save_and_open_page, I see just the text "pericoop".
So, for whatever reason it seems that the callback isn't fired.

Here's my rspec:

```
  scenario 'to multiple pericopes with valid attributes', js: true do
    fill_in 'pericoop 1', with: 'Jona 1:1 - 1:10'
    click_on 'Voeg nog een pericoop toe'
    should_see 'pericoop 2'
    fill_in 'pericoop 2', with: 'Jona 2:20 - 3:3'

    submit_form

    should_see 'Jona 1:1 - 10 | Jona 2:20 - 3:3'
  end
```

And the coffee-script

```
$ ->
  $("#pericopes").on "cocoon:after-insert", (event, added_item) ->
    num = $("#pericopes div.nested-fields").length
    added_item.find('.control-label').html('pericoop '+num)
    console.log('pericope numbered')
```

The console log is not displaying anything when run from the test (I've configured Firefox to keep the logs).

The form:

```
= simple_form_for studynote, validate: true do |f|
  #pericopes
    = f.simple_fields_for :pericopes do |ff|
      .nested-fields
        = ff.input :name,
                  label: "#{t('simple_form.labels.pericopes.name')} 1",
                  placeholder: 'Genesis 1:1-3:21',
                  autofocus: true
        = link_to_remove_association 'remove pericope', ff
    .links
      = link_to_add_association t('add_pericope'), f, :pericopes
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :note, :input_html => { :rows => 20 }    
  = f.button :submit, class: "btn-primary"
```

And the partial:

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :name,
            label: "#{ t('simple_form.labels.pericopes.name') }",
            placeholder: 'Genesis 1:1-3:21',
            autofocus: true
  = link_to_remove_association 'remove pericope', f
```

EDIT, I've refactored the form and the partial to dry up some code, hoping that this might solve the issue, but no luck yet.
Partial _pericope_fields.html.haml

```
.nested-fields
  - index = index
  = f.input :name,
            label: "#{ t('simple_form.labels.pericopes.name') } #{index}",
            placeholder: 'Genesis 1:1-3:21',
            autofocus: true
  = link_to_remove_association 'remove pericope', f
```

Form, _form.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for studynote, validate: true do |f|
  #pericopes
    = f.simple_fields_for :pericopes do |pericope|
      = render 'pericope_fields', f: pericope, index: 1
    .links
      = link_to_add_association t('add_pericope'), f, :pericopes, class: 'new btn-xs'
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :note, :input_html => { :rows => 20 }
  = f.button :submit, class: "btn-primary"
```

I've looked at this post, [300](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/399) but there the callbacks are not working at all.
And another post (that I can't find right now) where the spec did not include a js: true. But that's not the problem here.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: So for clarity: it works in the browser, just not in your tests, right? The only reason you assume it is not working, is because it does not log in the console. Could you make the js have an effect in html and test for that? (because I am not sure console logging is always captured correctly). Which javascript-driver are you using? Obviously it is a bit weird to test for a console logging in a feature test which is ment to be about black box testing :) (what the user sees) (so not sure that would be supported at all).

Comment: Yes, it works in the browser and not in the tests.
I am not testing for the console log, just added that for debugging purposes.
My test asserts that the text "pericoop 2" (should_see 'pericoop 2') should be present and that is where the test fails. And I can also see that failing when I add a save_and_open_page just before the assert.
I'm using selenium-webdriver as driver.

Comment: Ok. Weird. So either the javascript is not run (??) or the link is not clicked. Is that possible? You find the link by text, so maybe the text on the label is not the same. E.g. the standard locale in test is different or the translation has changed?

Comment: I'm sure the link is clicked, because a new field is shown on the page, only with the wrong label (without the index).
That's why I also assumed that the javascript is not run.

Comment: Ok. Getting weirder. Clicking the link also triggers javascript, otherwise the field would not be inserted (cocoon uses javascript to insert the new item).

Comment: Ha! Are you using turbolinks? Because your declaration of the callback is tightly linked to the presence of the `#pericopes` div and only on `ready` and not `turbolinks:load` (but that would also mean in your scenario you would have to come from e.g. a login page first)

Comment: No, I'm not using turbolinks. And yes, I login first in a before step.

Comment: I've done a small refactor to the form and partial to remove some duplication. But that did not solve the problem so far.
So what I understand right now is that the javascript is being called, because that adds the new fields, but it looks like the callback is not called when run from Rspec.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `should_see` syntax: does it wait for items to appear? For test insert a `sleep` statement, if that works ... Or write something like `Capybara.using_wait_time(3) do
      click_link('Click me')
      expect(page).to have_text("Has been clicked")
    end`

Comment: Hi Nathan, thank a lot for helping me here, that's really appreciated!

should_see is just a little helper method:
    `def should_see(text)
      expect(page).to have_content(text)
    end`

I tried the `sleep` and the `using_wait_time` but no results unfortunately.

Comment: Ok. Stumped. Could you create a minimal github project that reproduces the problem? Then I will have a look :)

Comment: Hi Nathan, the repo is https://github.com/andreheijstek/biblestudy_platform
The failing test is `bundle exec rspec spec/features/study_notes/creating_studynote_spec.rb:103`
This is the whole repo, but it isn't that big. I'm not sure what thing I should take out to make it really minimal for you (I'm not too experienced as programmer)

Comment: Thanks a lot Nathan, that really solves it! Thanks for your time!
Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation yet to accept your answer (or, it is accepted but not shown).

Comment: My pleasure! :) You could accept/upvote the answer :P

Comment: Accepted. Upvoting is beyond my powers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you especially configured it to be so, but the tests depended on the presence of compiled assets.

So either, you once compiled the assets and then forgot to do it again, so the `application.js` did not contain the latest version, or you never compiled the assets.

I simply disabled the compiled assets in test by editing the `config/environments/test.rb` file and adding

```
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
```

And then your tests seemed to work as expected (well two tests still failed: deleting studynotes and deleting pericopes but I am guessing that is something else).

> Note: I also had to edit your seeds, since a field `nr_of_verses` was renamed in a later migration to `nrofverses`.